# How can i make avatar hands with Leapmotion

Tags: motion-detection, leap-motion, avatar

I download and import 'Avatar Hand controller' with Leapmotion. And, I want using that source to make my own avatar hand controller. So, I download any avatar models and insert same script of 'Avatar Hand controller' into my avatar hands and fingers. But, hands of the downloaded avatar works well, my avatar doesn't work like this picture. The hand itself recognized, but arm stretches like a monster. 
How can I solve this? please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyJ9p.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a commercial Unity asset, you should ask for support from that developer.

The crux of the problem is that you (or the scripts involved) are applying translation to the hands, which causes this sort of stretching. You often only want to apply rotations from the Leap Motion data, not translation, but it really depends on how you are animating the avatar. For example, you could implement an IK solution to move the avatar's elbows to the Leap Motion elbow position and then use rotations from there -- or you could use IK to set the hand position and not use the Leap arm data at all. It is a fairly involved task.

There is some work to that end [here](https://github.com/leapmotion/UnityModules/tree/feature-Leap-IK-Blending/Assets), but I don't know how finished it is.